# Complex matrices and norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I have to prove for $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ this statement:

1. If $\left \| Ax \right \| \geq \gamma \left \| x \right \|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ with $\gamma > 0$ and any vector norm $\left \| . \right \|$, then exists $A^{-1}$ and $\left \| A^{-1} \right \| \leq \gamma^{-1}$ 
   for the matrix norm belonging to the vector norm.

Edit 1:

I tried this way:

I assumed $A$ is singular, which means that $detA = 0$ and from that, we conclude that there is an eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$. And because of it, there is an Eigenvector $x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ to $\lambda$ with $Ax=\lambda x = 0$. From that follows $$ \gamma \left \| x \right \| > 0 =\left \| Ax\right \| $$ which leads to contradiciton. I hope this one is correct.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I was thinking about using maybe the fact that if $\left \| \mathbb{I} - A \right \|\leq \beta < 1$ then is A non singular and $\left \| A^{-1} \right \|\leq 1/(1 - \beta )$ but not sure how to use it

Comment: You correctly proved that $A$ is non-singular. But now you need to prove the bound on $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to establish invertibility. Note that $x \neq 0$ implies that $\|Ax\| \geq \gamma \|x\| > 0$, which means that $Ax \neq 0$.  Thus, $A$ is a square matrix with a trivial nullspace, which means that it must be invertible.

A nice way to get the inequality: note that for all $x$, we have
$$
\|x\| = \|A(A^{-1}x)\| \geq \gamma \|A^{-1}x\|.
$$
Rearranging this inequality yields $\|A^{-1}x\| \leq \gamma^{-1}\|x\|$.  Now, by definition we have
$$
\|A^{-1}\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \|A^{-1}x\| \leq \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \gamma^{-1}\cdot \|x\| = \gamma^{-1}.
$$